# Did the cusp in the Boeing 377/C-97/KC-97’s fuselage structure cause fatigue problems?

Tags: aircraft-design, fuselage, fatigue, boeing-377-stratocruiser

The [Boeing 377 Stratocruiser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_377_Stratocruiser) - a civilian adaptation of the [C-97](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_C-97_Stratofreighter), a military transport which would also later be developed into the [KC-97](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_KC-97_Stratofreighter) - were derived from the [B-29](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_B-29_Superfortress)/[B-50](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_B-50_Superfortress) family by grafting a large, bulbous passenger/cargo compartment onto the B-29/50 fuselage; this created a sharp cusp in the fuselage cross-section, as can be seen in this photo of a half-built Stratocruiser:

[image: Stratocruiser fuselage cross-section]

([Image source](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_eqb8qL2GKZc/S7JNujnPOSI/AAAAAAAADl0/iz9rQRjHNYc/))

Such a sharp discontinuity in the fuselage profile would be expected to serve as a stress concentrator in a pressurised aircraft, like the 377/C-97/KC-97 series, and cause accelerated fatigue cracking in and around the cusp, shortening the lifespan of these fuselages; did these aircraft, in fact, experience fatigue problems emanating from the fuselage cusp, and, if so, how were they dealt with?

Comment: The floor in these aircraft takes part of the stress caused by the cabin pressure. It might not be as bad as it looks. But I am no expert in this stuff by any means :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the stress concentrating type of sharp corner. That is the natural shape that allows the parts to be in a nice smooth tension at lowest energy. If you made an elastic rubber balloon with a divider membrane creating two chambers and inflated it you would get a similar load distributing shape.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually see the same effect happening with soap bubbles when they touch and form a flat film connecting them. You can actually still see this type of fuselage in use in the Boeing 717 (Douglas/McDonnell Douglas DC-9). A lot of other narrowbody airliners also have it, but the outer panels fair over the intersection between the two fuselages.[image]